# WSL Win-Kex problem att VNCServer, X DISPLAY not found, any Help :D

Tags: linux, kali-linux, windows, vncviewer, tigervnc

**Hello, to day i tried to install kali Linux in my windows 10**
i need any help please

```
┌──(rootDESKTOP-KN54U4A)-[~]
└─# kex -start
```

***output:***

```
Error connecting to the KeX server.
Please try "kex start" to start the service.
If the server fails to start, please try "kex kill" or restart your WSL2 session and try again.


┌──(leader㉿DESKTOP-KN54U4A)-[~]
└─$ kex -s
```

***Output***

```
    Error connecting to the KeX server.
Please try "kex start" to start the service.
If the server fails to start, please try "kex kill" or restart your WSL2 session and try again.
and i get message Sayes: TigerVNC Viewr: Unable to connect to socket: connection refused (10061)
```

┌──(leader㉿DESKTOP-KN54U4A)-[~]
└─$ kex kill

***Output***

```
 tigervncserver: No matching VNC server running for this user!
tigervncserver: No matching VNC server running for this user!
tigervncserver: No matching VNC server running for this user!
tigervncserver: No matching VNC server running for this user
```

!

```
┌──(rootDESKTOP-KN54U4A)-[~]
└─# vncserver
```

***output:***

```
    Killing Xtigervnc process ID 13260... success!

=================== tail /root/.vnc/DESKTOP-KN54U4A.localdomain:5901.log ===================

Xvnc TigerVNC 1.11.0 - built 2021-03-22 21:21
Copyright (C) 1999-2020 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.rst)
See https://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.
Underlying X server release 12010000, The X.Org Foundation


Mon Jul 12 18:37:40 2021
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on local interface(s), port 5901
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0

Mon Jul 12 18:38:11 2021
 ComparingUpdateTracker: 0 pixels in / 0 pixels out
 ComparingUpdateTracker: (1:-nan ratio)
============================================================================================

vncserver: /usr/bin/Xtigervnc did not start up, please look into '/root/.vnc/DESKTOP-KN54U4A.localdomain:5901.log' to determine the reason! -1


┌──(rootDESKTOP-KN54U4A)-[~]
└─# tail /root/.vnc/DESKTOP-KN54U4A.localdomain:5901.log
```

***output:***

```
    Mon Jul 12 18:37:40 2021
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on local interface(s), port 5901
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0

Mon Jul 12 18:38:11 2021
 ComparingUpdateTracker: 0 pixels in / 0 pixels out
 ComparingUpdateTracker: (1:-nan ratio)

┌──(rootDESKTOP-KN54U4A)-[~]
└─# vncserver --list
```

***Output:***

```
    TigerVNC server sessions:

X DISPLAY #     RFB PORT #      PROCESS ID      SERVER
```

**i need some help to that please :D and sorry 4 bad English :)
all what i need is open kex -sl in my machine**

Comment: I don't pretend that I know anything about running a GUI version of Kali in WSL, but the error message suggests you run `kex start`, which you never do.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do `sudo su` (all the commands need to be performed by root user) ;
2. Delete the symlink in `/tmp/.X11-unix` ( just do `rm /tmp/.X11-unix`) ;
3. Run `vncserver` (It will now be able to create the server) ;
4. Run `kex` and everything should work.

Comment: Why `sudo su` rather than just `sudo -s` (or `sudo -i`)?

Comment: it can work either way